# How do you create an inline edit button for ASP.NET MVC Core, not using the Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried various things, but I have this incomplete snippet,

```
 @foreach (var student in @Model)
    {
            <tr>

                <td><input name="student_number" value="@Student.student_number"/></td>
                <td><input name="work-date" value=@Student.work_date/></td>
                <td><input name="last-name" value=@Student.last_name/></td>
                <td><input name="first-name" value=@Student.first_name/></td>
                <td><a asp-controller="HelloWorld" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Student.student_id">Edit</a> </td>
            </tr>
    }
```

The Edit link created is a expected, "/HelloWorld/Edit/1".

How do I get the other values?  If this was a form, it would send them.  What do I do in this case?  Is there a special way to do this other than create a form element and change the button to a Submit?  Other than that I only know to build a link manually with the values, but that does not sound right.

If it matters I am using Dapper.  I say that because it seems that all the examples I look at have the Entity Framework generate CRUD, and the examples don't show what the HTML in the View looks like.

Comment: Too be hontest, your tags are completely unrelated. The question is completely unrelated to ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core. It's about JavaScript/Ajax. You'll need to read the fields via javascript (choose any library that fits your needs) and send an ajax request back to your server. But then you need to rework your services and use "WebApI" controllers (which don't return views but json). And on a side note, its not even valid HTML5. There is no `name` attribute on `<td>` and as far as I know also no tag helper. Did you confused that with `Id`?

Comment: @Tseng No.  I just didn't put it in the right type of element.  I will fix it.

Comment: I fixed it.  I put them all in input elements.

Comment: @Tseng I think you are confirming my thoughts.  There is no native ".NET way."  I have to build it to hit the server manually, a whole page refresh, or I have to use Ajax.  There's know built-in way to get that edit link to have the input elements there automatically.  I thought there might be since it has the asp-* helpers.

Comment: Tag helpers are only that, helpers. They help you create reusable code, which better blends into HTML and hence offer better HTML syntax than @Html utilities. There is no magic behind it. Using `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "HelloWorld", new { id = Student.student_id })` is same as `<a asp-controller="HelloWorld" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Student.student_id">Edit</a>`,but later is easier to read and you can easier add new classes and get css class intellisense where you don't get that with the `@Html.ActionLink` method.Also you have more control over the html created with the later

Comment: @Tseng using asp-route-* captures what I currently have in the results when the table is built.  How can I get what the edited value is, so I can send it to my controller to update my database?

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many `asp-route-*` attributes as you need to fill your route parameters.

You html tag could just as easily be:

```
<a asp-controller="HelloWorld" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Student.student_id" asp-route-first="@Student.first_name">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Mike, Is this the same as "attribute routing"?

Comment: This captures what I currently have, not the changes for the edit.